# Ajax Form not Working,New page opens and success code prints on page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form having 3 fields. I want to submit the form through an ajax call but I am having a problem submitting.  My call to bind ajaxform does not work.  I don't know what causes this problem.

My JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("rock");
    $('#writeSubmit').bind('click', function (event) {
        alert("after submit");
        $('#writeReviewAjaxForm').ajaxSubmit({
            target: $('#response')
        });
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="write-review-form" class="write-review">
    <h3><spring:theme code="pdp.write.review" text="Write a Review" /> </h3>
    <form:form id="writeReviewAjaxForm" commandName="reviewForm" method="post" action="${productCode}/write-review">

        <div class="field-container required">
            <label for="myname">
                <spring:theme code="pdp.write.headline" text="Headline" />
            </label>
            <form:input path="headline" />
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
            <spring:theme code="pdp.write.rating" text="Rating" />
            <br>
            <form:select path="rating">
                <form:option value='1'>&#9733</form:option>
                <form:option value='2'>&#9733 &#9733</form:option>
                <form:option value='3'>&#9733 &#9733 &#9733</form:option>
                <form:option value='4'>&#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733</form:option>
                <form:option value='5'>&#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733 &#9733</form:option>
            </form:select>
        </div>
        <div class="field-container">
            <label for="review">
                <spring:theme code="pdp.write.review.yourReview" text="Your Review" />
            </label>
            <form:textarea path="comment" />    
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Review" id="writeSubmit" class="btn" />    
    </form:form>
</div>

<div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have your jquery plugin included.

like [Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

but in this plugin you don't need to click event on submit you can simply use:

```
<script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding to the click event on `$('#writeSubmit')` you should instead bind the event on form submit and prevent form submit and instead use `.ajaxSubmit`

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("rock");
    $('#writeReviewAjaxForm').bind('submit', function (event) {
        alert("on submit");
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#writeReviewAjaxForm').ajaxSubmit({
            target: $('#response')
        });
    });
});
```

This should work for your use case, since the click would normally trigger form submit event which was not stopped. Hence if you check your network requests / server log, the form would have submitted twice, once by the default browser and once by the `ajaxSubmit` javascript call.